# onLongClick is not working on Webview, OS - 4.1

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean, textselection

I have custom web view which extends to Webview class, in that class I have implemented OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener. However on long pressing text in webview its not calling onLongClick() method in tablet with OS version 4.1.2 & **it does call method onLongClick() for OS 3.2**. Please help me . I am using sample code from [the BTAndroidWebViewSelection project](https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection).

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659134/onlongclicklistener-does-not-work-on-webview

Comment: @amrinder007 Thanks man, your given link have solved my problem, now I'm able to clone onLongClick(), however I have one problem, on long press I'm showing my custom pop-up window & it comes but it also show the default text selection option at the place of action bar, how to overcome on this so that it will show only my custom pop up otions. Thanks.

Comment: But why onLongClick() method stops working for android os version 4.1 ? Anybody have tried this interface http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html on OS 4.1.