# How to override webview's text selection context menu?

Tags: android, webview, contextmenu

I have a requirement like when i long press on the text in my web view by clicking long press, i should set my custom context menu items instead of "select", "select all", "web search".

Please help me.

[image]

Would like to override these default "select all", "copy", "share", "web search". in this place wanna place my custom menus.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection) question .

Comment: May be this answer can help you: [How to override default text selection of android webview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22563790/2722270), and this [Use a custom contextual action bar for WebView text selection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22336903/2722270)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you need to extend from WebView class and override `onCreateContextMenu` method.

See [Use a custom contextual action bar for WebView text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection)

Answer (score 3):

you can do some custom in activity method: onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode),
just like this:

```
@Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        menu.clear();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU, menu);
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
        // get custom menu item
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menuItems.add(menu.getItem(i));
        }
        menu.clear();
        // reset menu item order
        int size = menuItems.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            addMenuItem(menu, menuItems.get(i), i, true);
        }
        super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    }
}


/**
 * add custom item to menu
 * @param menu
 * @param item
 * @param order
 * @param isClick
 */
private void addMenuItem(Menu menu, MenuItem item, int order, boolean isClick){
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(item.getGroupId(),
            item.getItemId(),
            order,
            item.getTitle());
    menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    if (isClick)
        // set custom menu item click
        menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}
```