# android how get url in page loaded- loading

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

hello everyone i want to know if there is any way to find
url in page loaded in webview
for example

```
webview.loadurl("stackoverflow.com") // this is url 
string aa = -webivew.geturl() //in this way in kno url in adress bar
```

BUT I want to know url of "help" >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=android%20how%20get%20url%20in%20page%20loaded-%20loading#

or something else without clik on it is this possible ?

i think with jsoup there is way or not ?
i'm confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "*i want to know url of help*" ?

Comment: @Raid it was a example
i just want to know 
one specific url from website
without click on it
for example 
mychannel url, from page Youtube.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a first client in your WebView : WebViewClient, in which you'll call the html :

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   webview1.loadUrl("javascript:alert(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);");
   }
```

And then, put a second client :

```
webview1.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

And in the WebChromeClient, put this, after having declared a boolean navigationTolink to false:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onJsAlert(final WebView view, String url, final String transfert, JsResult result) {
             if (!navigationtoLink) {
                Document html = Jsoup.parse(transfert);
                Elements links = html.select("a[href]");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    if (link.attr("href").contains("youtube.com")) { 
                    view.loadUrl(link.attr("href"));
                    navigationtoLink=true;
                }
             }

    }
```

[This](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) can help for grabbing

Comment: GROSSMANN, thanks for reply
i was searching something like to know
specific url in loaded in webview( or from website)
example 
link=youtube.com
i want to know , Url of my Channel without click on it
is it possible ?

Comment: thanks grossmann, im trying to test
i will tell you if it works

Comment: if(link.contains <---giving error cannot resolve method java.lang.String

Comment: FIRST OF ALL HAPPY NEW YEAR 
webview.load <--error cannot resolve as method ?
or i have to write, webview.loaddata()
webview.loadurl()<--its wrong i kknow
<  Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); ERROR DOC- CANNOT RESOLVE SYMBOL DOC

Comment: @user3565993 Happy new year too. I just edited the code. Should be OK now :-)

Comment: hello Stephane: i think your code is working, but its not working<br/>with what i was doing<br/>`your code  for find link and make a toast ---> Link Found 
i tryied but nothing to do
can u help me ?`

Comment: @user3565993 Once you have the link, you can do everything with it, even toast it : replace the line view.loadUrl(link... with your toast. I don't really understand where the problem is.

Comment: i want to change title in actionbar,
<br> Found<--in title

Comment: getActionBar().setTitle("Found"); Thanks to accept solution

Comment: just another thing bro; its working but...
in javascript alert it show all source-code of page, is there way to do all in background ? or with another webview in backround
thanks for helping

Comment: @user3565993 Yes, just add webView1.setVisibility(View.GONE); after creation, to hide it

Comment: any link for ?longpress menu in webview
can't find tutorial....all tutorials are with button
thanks for helping bro

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659134/onlongclicklistener-does-not-work-on-webview :-)

Comment: Can you helpme with this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911894/android-activity-screenshot-how

Comment: Sure, but you should ask a new question, with your code and describe where the problem is

Comment: Allready asked bro; and pasted what code im using; that is my question;;

Comment: Ok, didn't see it was u :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get all links/URLs from your webView, you need a html parser to iterate the page content.
Then, you can loop the result list and check if it contains your *Youtube Channel url* or the url that you are looking for.

1) You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), this is an example (taken from [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) ):

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // get all "a" elements with "href"
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.png]");// get all "img" with src ending .png

Element masthead = doc.select("div.masthead").first();
```

2) OR use [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) library.

```
public static List<String> getLinksOnPage(final String url) {
    final Parser htmlParser = new Parser(url);
    final List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();

    try {
        final NodeList tagNodeList = htmlParser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new NodeClassFilter(LinkTag.class));
        for (int j = 0; j < tagNodeList.size(); j++) {
            final LinkTag loopLink = (LinkTag) tagNodeList.elementAt(j);
            final String loopLinkStr = loopLink.getLink();
            result.add(loopLinkStr);
        }
    } catch (ParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO handle error
    }

    return result;
}
```

3) OR create your own parser, something like:

```
String HTMLPage; // get the HTML page as a String
Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("(<a[^>]+>.+?</a>)",  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher pageMatcher = linkPattern.matcher(HTMLPage);
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
while(pageMatcher.find()){
    links.add(pageMatcher.group());
}
```

`links` ArrayList will contains all links in the page.

PS: You can edit `linkPattern` to filter some links.

Comment: Euuh! not really advanced. Whatever, if you never try you'll never learn ;)

Comment: yeah you are right, jsoup is good 
but i dnt know how to start it
it give me error
cannot resolve method java.lang.String 
i was trying grossmann method with JSOUPP