# from a file into an array of String []

Tags: android, list, file, android-listview, android-file

I have a *small* server that contains the **text file**  which can be that is similar to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:59777/smb/192.168.0.250/Files/Interstellar.mp4
http://127.0.0.1:59777/smb/192.168.0.250/Files/уаау.mp4
http://127.0.0.1:59777/smb/192.168.0.250/Files/possible.mp4
```

and in my program have `listView` which to build a list of uses which should be built from a list in the file , and so I have 2 questions .
1) Is it possible to access the file via URL? If so then the question number **2** .
2) as soon as possible via the URL to read data from a file into an array of String []

```
        private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
        "Text #2",
        "Text #3","Text #4","Text #5" };
```

passer on ?

Comment: First: what have you tried so far?  Second: localhost is exactly localhost - the device /emulator itself.

Comment: `1) Is it possible to access the file via URL?`  Yes.  `2) as soon as possible via the URL to read data from a file into an array of String []` Yes

Comment: @Simon, can give a very simple example code , if not difficult , would be very plagodaren well, or link.

Answer (score 0):

In short :

- Load your url in a webview
- Add two clients to your webview, like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694792/1994349)
- split your html with html.split("\n");

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("www.yoursite.com/file.txt");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str = in.readLine();
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    in.close();
}
```

and see this link in order to put it in a list:
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/listviewwebservice.php