# android activity screenshot how?

Tags: android, screenshot

Hello Friends i'm making a app with webview
i want to take screenshot of my activity
Currnetly i'm using this code for  capture image

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
   View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
   rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
```

And This for Save

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

It sometime Works and sometime not, i mean ,sometime i can see in gallery screenshot and sometime not
i want to if there is any option to show captured screenshot
Like whhen we press Vol+power button

Main problem is how can i show image when its taken
or know if its taken or not 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to open dialog after image is saved to show the result.

Comment: can you give me an example link 
thanks i ìn advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample approach: save your image -> display result with dialog. And to make it available in Android Gallery, the file path should also be changed:

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File imagePath = new File(path, "screenshot.png");//now gallery can see it
FileOutputStream fos;
 try {
     fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
     bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
     fos.flush();
     fos.close();

     displayResult(imagePath.getAbsolutePath())// here you display your result after saving
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
 }
}
```

Create another method call `displayResult` to see the result:

```
public void displayResult(String imagePath){

    //LinearLayOut Setup
    LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    //ImageView Setup
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);//you need control the context of Imageview

    //Diaglog setup
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);//you need control the context of this dialog
    dialog.setContentView(imageView);

   imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

   //Display result
   imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
   dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nguyen Doan Tung;;
Working With Your Method;;
But i cant see Screenshot in Gallery;;
is There any way to see in Gallery Screenshot ;; caputured

Comment: Thanks Dude, its working now ; i used sendbroadcast(intent) method its wrking

Comment: @user3565993 can you please explain how you used sendboardcast(intent)

Answer (score 0):

Other people have run into issues when trying to get a bitmap from a view's Drawing Cache.

Rather than trying to use the drawing cache, you can instead just get the bitmap directly from the view. Google's DynamicListView example uses the following function to do so.

```
 /** Returns a bitmap showing a screenshot of the view passed in. */
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: hello Dave S; how can i call this function?
Bitmap bitmap= getBitmapFromView( ? what ?);

Comment: "return getBitmapFromView(rootView)" in takeScreenshot()'s last line

Comment: hello -stephane ;; i tried it in this way ;; public
` Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
   View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
   
   return return getBitmapFromView(rootView);
}`
Nothing happenned ; i think screenshot is not saving

Comment: Well I can assure you the function works, I'm using it in my app right now. It may be an issue with how you are saving or verifying the screen shot. Can you edit your answer with more of the code and show how you are trying to use it?

Comment: Thanks Dave, With Your Method and Nguyen duan Tung Method i can take screenshot ;;
but ;;;
its visibile in file manager and not in Gallery