# How to get url after loading page in webview

Tags: android, webview

I need to take url after loading a web page in my web view to check condition and if I use onPageFinished() method, then where to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149260/3154636

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693490/android-how-get-url-in-page-loaded-loading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen for a WebView finishing loading a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149216/how-to-listen-for-a-webview-finishing-loading-a-url)

Comment: @aminpinjari where should I use that method, either in same Activity or in the other class. If in another class, how to use

Comment: use it in same class where your webview is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Just set a webview client and override onpagefinished as shown below

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

inside onpagefinished you have the url